# Sapper: Getting 'FetchEvent for "<url>" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.' under docker

Tags: docker, svelte, sapper

**Setup**:
I am new to Sapper (and also web development).
I have been learning Sapper and trying to build a web app consisting of:

1. A database server (mysql)
2. A backend (beego)
3. A frontend (sapper)

Each of them is dockerized using docker-compose and I have a user-defined network. Something like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    networks:
      - fullstack_network
    ...

  api:
    networks:
      - fullstack_network
    ...

  frontend:
    environment:
      # The env variable will be used as the base URL to the backend (api)
      - API_ENDPOINT=http://api:8082
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - fullstack_network
    ...

networks:
  fullstack_network:
```

**Problem:**

On the frontend (dockerized), I have a page called `foo`. When the page is clicked, I want to make an API call to the backend API that returns a JSON.

I make the API call on the preload function as I have been trying to implement [Sapper's preloading](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Preloading).
It always throws an error 500:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

I see a warning from the console:

> The FetchEvent for "http://api:8082/v1/foo" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.

The only way to get a successful result is to refresh the page, which is not okay.

Note: If the frontend is not dockerized, I don't encounter this error at all.

Here is my `routes/foo.svelte`:

```
<script context="module">
    import {API_ENDPOINT} from "../components/Config.js"

    export async function preload(page, {env}) {
        let api_endpoint = API_ENDPOINT;

        if (env['API_ENDPOINT'] !== undefined) {
            api_endpoint = env['API_ENDPOINT'];
        }

        let url = api_endpoint + "/v1/foo";
        // when dockerized, the url is "http://api:8082/v1/foo"
        // when it is not dockerized, the url is "http://localhost:8080/v1/foo", because I make the backend (api) accessible from the host machine. 
        const response = await this.fetch(url);
        if (response.ok) {
            const json = await response.json();
            return {
                 results: json
            };
        } else {
            throw new Error("Fetch foo failed!");
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let results;
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>Foo</title>
</svelte:head>
<p>
    This is the foo overview.
</p>

{#await results}
    <p>fetching ...</p>
{:then results}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(results, null, 2)}</pre>
{:catch error}
    <div class="error">Unable to fetch the data! <br/>
        {error}
    </div>
{/await}
```

Could you help me find the root cause and the fix? An explanation why the problem occurred is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have anything to do with Svelte nor Sapper. When you type the url `http://api:8082/v1/foo` in a browser do you get the data you expect? If not it means the address api:8082 is not accessible outside the docker.

Comment: Thanks! I re-read the preload documentation that the code inside the preload blocks may run on either the server or in the client browser.
 
When the API call runs on the server (within the docker container), ``http://api:8082`` is accessible, because the frontend shares the same network as the backend api . That explains why refreshing the page (i.e. pressing the F5 button) works.
When the code runs on the browser, ``http://api:8082`` is not accessible.

One way to solve it is to use a fixed address or FQDN for the backend that is accessible both inside and outside the docker container.